# Publish MVC Website as A Single DLL File / Encrypted

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here it is my problem:

I developed an MVC site and currently using standard method to publish which will placed files & folders inside the server. All dll files go under BIN folder and so on with the Content and Views go to Content & Views folder.

The problem is this website is an admin panel designed for commercial hardware device (embedded windows OS), so exposing the views and content as a plain text file can't be an option since it will open vulnerability of hijacking/code stealing. Even the device will be packed in a sealed box, anyone who buy it can broke the case and when they are knowing that the device run in windows environment then anything of security breach may happen, including stole the views code to be copied/changed for any purpose.

So I would need to secure the MVC files. I imagine if MVC can be published in secure files, e.g put all the content and views inside dll files.

Comment: You can put the files in database and extract at run time... check Microsoft's DNN it uses almost the same technique..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default there is an assumption that whoever has access to your views and DLLs is trusted. If they have your files, they can do whatever they want with them.

By the nature of HTML, there is no point in trying to conceal your *content* files such as javascript and CSS. These files are served to the client regardless, so they are always retrievable.

If you want to put your views into DLLs, you can look into **[RazorGenerator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator)**.

> A Custom Tool for Visual Studio that allows processing Razor files at design time instead of runtime, **allowing them to be built into an assembly** for simpler reuse and distribution.

Please note that what you're doing is known as **[security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)**.

> [ ... ] **security through obscurity** is the use of secrecy of the design or implementation to provide security

---

> Security through obscurity is discouraged and not recommended by standards bodies.

Answer (score 0):

MVC views should never contain business logic, only formatting logic and that is it. Moreover, since C# code is compiled into Intermediate Language (IL), anyone can reverse the process and get the source code.

In such case, you need an obfuscator to mingle the IL to make it difficult to hack, but that this not 100% guaranteed to prevent hackers from reverse engineer you IL (DLL and exe).

The best thing to do is to establish a comprehensive way of testing the admin panel and to facilitate a robust update process, so in case anything went wrong, you push your updates as quickly as possible.